# Passing data in HTML data attribute using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

### SOLVED - see last comment under this post.

I'm trying to pass and retrieve JSON data in a hidden variable and coming up against a strange situation. I've been racking my brains and searching everywhere to find out why - I'm sure its something stupid but I can't think what...:

1. line 504 & 508 show the correct data (except for the description field which is the only field which was changed) but line 509 shows an additional  object under _attachments which doesn't exist in the other two - why?
2. line 509 - the header line description text differs from the description text in the object body - the body description is the correct one.

The logs were taken from chromium, but firefox exhibits the same behaviour.
See the code below and the console logs.

```
503 var pp = $("#new-event-page").find("input[name=event_data]").val();
504 console.log(pp);
505 // comment
506 var paramx = JSON.parse(pp);
507 //comment
508 console.log(JSON.stringify(paramx));
509 console.log(paramx);
```

The output of the console log is as follows (after a bit of manual formatting):

```
testa.js:504--{"name":"Untitled-1369464011",
               "description":"Previously aadded image - only this text is updated",
               "occurred":"2013-05-25",
               "group":"empty",
               "category":"empty",
               "_attachments":{"globe.png":{"content_type":"image/png",
                                            "digest":"md5d8ba0496f16bdf74d6310432abf2a530"}},
                "_id":"0C1CA0F4-2DF4-46F2-9D35-415674D6452A",
                "_rev":"5-1d108457b606cc4388160ca46ffefbbf"}
testa.js:508--{"name":"Untitled-1369464011",
               "description":"Previously aadded image - only this text is updated",
               "occurred":"2013-05-25",
               "group":"empty",
               "category":"empty",
               "_attachments":{"globe.png":{"content_type":"image/png",
               "digest":"md5-d8ba0496f16bdf74d6310432abf2a530"}},
               "_id":"0C1CA0F4-2DF4-46F2-9D35-415674D6452A",
               "_rev":"5-1d108457b606cc4388160ca46ffefbbf"}
testa.js:509--Object {name: "Untitled-1369464011", description: "Previously aadded image - only this text is updated", occurred: "2013-05-25", group: "empty", category: "empty"…}
    _attachments: Object
       globe.png: Object
          content_type: "image/png"
          __proto__: Object
       opAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC: Object
          content_type: undefined
          __proto__: Object
     __proto__: Object
     _id: "0C1CA0F4-2DF4-46F2-9D35-415674D6452A"
     _rev: "6-001ee0c89c5b9dbe2b06e5b926ad446d"
     category: "empty"
     description: "Previously aadded image - only this text is updated -pass 2"
     group: "empty"
     name: "Untitled-1369464011"
     occurred: "2013-05-25"
     __proto__: Object
```

Comment: I just noticed a small difference between 504 and 508 - the md5 digest attribute has an extra '-', which adds to the mystery...

Comment: Just noticed something else - the _rev parameter in 509 is different from 504 and 508 which further adds to the mystery - the rev parameter should only get updated when the record is written to the database...based on the code sample above, how is this behaviour even possible?

Comment: Is there something about variable scope that I'm not understanding? (forget the MD5 difference - it was a cut/paste issue)

Comment: Solved. It was a question of me assuming that firebug/chrome kept a snapshot of the state of the objects - but it doesn't it keeps a reference to the object - just like in the code. So if the object is updated later, then the debugger view of the object contents are updated to the last state of the object. Only way to track these down is to step through the debugger and examine the objects in real-time. My bad - and lack of experience.

Comment: A final comment (for newbies like me :P)- the way round the mutating object is to do console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) - that way the snapshot is maintained correctly...if the object is small

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I can see no error in `FF 21`:
http://jsfiddle.net/A3tex/

gives:
[image]

Comment: It shouldn't have any difference, which is what is bothering me